# how to use git command with MSBuild?

Tags: .net, git, msbuild, xbuild

I'm thinking about using **git submodules** to retrieve dependencies of my git repository instead of committing binary files to my main repository (effectively only committing binary files to a different repository which I will be able to purge often --by purge I mean delete history to save space on the server...).

Problem is, how to call the GIT executable using MSBuild? In the developer machine git should already be in the path, but in the buildagents the path to git executable is going to come from an environment variable. How to figure out the git path then at compile time using MSBuild? I want to do a git pull of the git submodule every time I build.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You read the environment variables in MSBuild much the same way you would a property

So if the environment variable being passed is `GIT_PATH`, you can access it using `$(GIT_PATH)`

Supply this to the `exec` task along with the appropriate arguments

Comment: Yeh thanks but what to do to check first if "git" command is already accessible, before checking the env var?

Comment: @knocte You can do ( again with exec task) a `where git` and see if git is already on PATH

Comment: manojlds, I still can't figure out how to do this, because "where git" doesn't generate a different exitCode than a call that doesn't return a valid path (for example "where somecommandthatdoesnotexist", still returns an exitCode==1).

Comment: So what I just want to do with MSBuild is the following, in pseudocode:
var gitPath = Where("git");
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(gitPath))
  gitPath = Environment.GetVariable("GITPATH");
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(gitPath))
  throw new Exception ("git is not installed; install it or specify its path in the GITPATH env var")
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = gitPath;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "foo";
p.Start ();

Comment: The documentation for the "where" command states that it returns an exitcode of 0 when it finds a valid match, a 1 when it doesn't and a 2 when there's an error. It always works as documented for me.